# How to create mongodb collection with default data using mongoose js + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am developing a Rest API using NodeJS + Mongodb (mongoose). I want to create a collection with some default documents.

e.g.

```
masterData = [
    {
        "name": "pdf",
        "description" : "file format for PDF file",
        "category":"fileType"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "video",
        "description" : "file format for mov, mp4 files",
        "category":"fileType"
    },
    {
        "name": "html",
        "description" : "file format for html documents ",
        "category":"fileType"
    }
];
```

I want to create above records when the collection is created.

Is there any prescribed way to achieve this functionality other than writing code to check and add default documents?